# Finding installed software/Disregarding common OS softwares

Tags: windows, powershell, installed-applications

I am attempting to update a script we currently have at my position. My want is to be able to pull up a list of installed software on a PC however, I would like to exclude things such as "Windows Redistributables" & other OS-standard programs. I am not sure if I would have to make a text file with the full names of the programs verbatim and have the command run and exclude those names or if their is a simpler way to do that. Which is why I am here. The current command we use is listed below.

`Get-InstalledSoftware -Computername $env:computername | Select-Object Name,Version,ComputerName |Format-table`

Comment: Assuming `Get-InstalledSoftware` is a custom function built by someone in your company, I would recommend modifying the code to add an extra `-Exclude` parameter for *built-in* functionality. Other than that, you can use a filter cmdlet such as `Where-Object` to filter out the unwanted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Possibility filter out anything with Microsoft in the Name.

```
Get-InstalledSoftware -Computername $env:computername | 
   Where-Object Name -NotLike "*Microsoft*"           |
   Select-Object Name,Version,ComputerName            |
   Format-table
```

Comment: So, after running this it does work. So, firstly, thank you very much; Secondly, would it be at all possible to put this into a .txt and have it run through the txt file to make the code a little cleaner (as in run the ```Where-Object Name -NotLike``` list as a single command through a .txt file or something akin to that?

Comment: @SammyD007, the code is written like that for ease of readability. It will run as written no need to have it on a single line. If you want to save it paste the code into Notepad and then save it as a .ps1 file and you can run it from the PowerShell command prompt.
If the answer meets your needs please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.